# Variable being used without being initialized

Tags: c++, variables, initialization

So the variable `hoursWorked` is not initialized. But how am I supposed to initialize it if I want it to equal whatever the user stores in it? For example I want `hoursWorked` to be whatever any person outputs in it in `cin`. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () 
{
   //Declare Variables
   double hoursWorked;
   double payRate;
   double incomeBeforeTax;

   payRate = 15;
   incomeBeforeTax = payRate * hoursWorked;

   cout << "Enter hours worked: ";
   cin >> hoursWorked;
   cout << endl;
   cout << incomeBeforeTax << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first thing to get from this is that C++ is not a symbolic processing language. It doesn't "memorize" that `incomeBeforeTax` is supposed to be `payRate * hoursWorked`.

Comment: Why can't you take input before calculation?

Comment: @ coding Mash..... cin >> hoursWorked; double hoursWorked;   ??

Comment: You could change incomeBeforeTax to be a lambda function.  `auto incomeBeforeTax = [&](){ return payRate * hoursWorked; };`  Then the value it returns will vary with payRate and hoursWorked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation of `incomeBeforeTax` which references `hoursWorked` needs to occur after you initialize it by reading from `cin`. Move that line after `cin >> hoursWorked;` and it will work:

```
payRate = 15.0;

cout << "Enter hours worked: ";
cin >> hoursWorked;

incomeBeforeTax = payRate * hoursWorked;

cout << endl;
cout << incomeBeforeTax << endl;
```

C++, like most procedural languages evaluates your code in the order in which it is written. That is, `incomeBeforeTax = payRate * hoursWorked;` assigns a value to `incomeBeforeTax` based on the current values of `payRate` and `hoursWorked`. These must be defined and initialized before the assignment is performed. That is what `cin >> hoursWorked` does.

On a side note, `double` variables are best initialized with `double` literals so add `.0` to the value.

Comment: What's wrong with initializing doubles with integer constants? A good compiler will do the right thing.

Comment: OMG thank you so much it worked.....
What was I doing wrong?
@ Alexey I'm using MSVS c++ express

Comment: C++ runs each line in order, generally speaking, short of anything that messes with flow control (for, while, goto, etc.). The way you had it, you wrote "multiply payRate by hoursWorked and store it in incomeBeforeTax", but hoursWorked has no value yet. Nothing has written to it. You are not defining/declaring what incomeBeforeTax is in C++, you are instructing it to, when it executes that line, execute that logic.

Comment: @DavidCamacho I've added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Oh I thought the problem was when I declared double hoursWorked;
Not in the equation incomeBeforeTax = hoursWorked * payRate;
Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
incomeBeforeTax = payRate * hoursWorked;
```

before `hoursWorked` has been initialized, you seem to indicate the intent of what `incomeBeforeTax` needs to be. One way to preserve that intent is to create a function and use the function whenever you need `incomeBeforeTax`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () 
{
   //Declare Variables
   double hoursWorked;
   double payRate;

   // Define a function that encodes the intent of what
   // incomeBeforeTax needs to be.
   auto incomeBeforeTax = [&]() { return payRate*hoursWorked; };

   payRate = 15;

   cout << "Enter hours worked: ";
   cin >> hoursWorked;
   cout << endl;
   cout << incomeBeforeTax() << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```